# Plone4 collection - page by page visualization misbehaviour

Tags: collections, plone

My plone collection folder doesn't show all items when using the page by page view. Basically I have 9 pages with elements, but pages 6 - 8 show exactly the same content. Therefore not all items are displayed, even if the total number of items corrispond to the elements that should be in the collection.
Here's the [link](http://www.innovationfestival.bz.it/it/media/coll-rassegna) to the page.

Setting the collection to display all items on one page or more items per page (100 instead of 20), the visualization is correct and elements starting with "20120921..." appear. You can see it at this [link](http://www.innovationfestival.bz.it/de/media/coll-pressespiegel).

It shouldn't be a matter of collection filters since the elements are there, but maybe a visualization bug. Executing "Update catalog" didn't help.
Using Plone 4109 and Zope 2.13.8

Did someone else notice this behaviour, or what could be the cause?
Thanks a lot for any hint!

Comment: Are you using a caching proxy such as varnish?

Comment: No, only a simple webserver. Working directly on the instance gives me the same result.

Comment: So pages 1-5 show the first 100 items, after which your pages start repeating items 101-120, right? Any customizations or is this straight up Plone?

Comment: Right, except the last page shows again the correct entries. It's basically standard plone with a custom theme including some views and some eggs too, but not regarding collections in particular.

Comment: The last page is 'special' in that it has to deal with orphans and a smaller 'rest' set. If this can be reproduced on a new site, then you may well have found a Plone or Zope bug.

Comment: On this zope instance I've 2 sites with mount points. Tested a collection on the other plone page (with a different theme), items 0-80 are correct, then it starts repeating until the 7th (last) page.

Comment: interesting, so it's either something local (mount points, extra package that messes things up, etc). You now need to see if this is reproducible on a plain Plone site, no add-ons, no mount points.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is likely related to a bug in Products.ZCatalog that was fixed with the following changelog entry: "Fixed incorrect calculation of batches in the second half of the result set in sortResults." I would recommend upgrading to the latest version of Zope 2.13 (2.13.23, to be precise).

Comment: which versions of Plone are affected by this bug?

Comment: Thanks for your inputs, upgraded to Zope 2.13.19 and the problem is solved now!